# Elastic search query to return documents matching all elements in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a structure similar to this:

Document 1:

```
nestedobject: {
uniqueid: "12345",
field: [ {id: 1,
          color: blue,
         fruit:banana},
{id: 2,
          color: red,
fruit:apple},
]
}
```

Document 2: (in same index)

```
nestedobject: {
uniqueid:23456,
field: [ {id: 3,
          color: blue, 
fruit:banana},
{id: 4,
          color: blue,
fruit:banana},
]
}
```

**the field mappings can be seen as :**

```
{"mappings":
 "nestedobject":{
"properties":{
"uniqueid":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
"keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
}
}
}
"field":{
"type":"nested",
"id":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
"keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
}
}
},
"color":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
"keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
}
}
},
"fruit":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
"keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Now, I try to query this index with 2 documents and I want only the document which has all the elements in the field array with color blue and fruit as banana -  NOT ATLEAST 1.

Right now, with the query, I get returned both the documents as it matches with the first element of the first document and returns that.

How to make this possible?

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "nestedobject.field",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"nestedobject.field.color" : "blue"} },
                    { "match" : {"nestedobject.field.fruit" : "banana"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to the below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "field",
            "query": {
              "match":{
                "field.color": "blue"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "field",
            "query": {
              "match":{
                "field.fruit": "banana"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that there are two [Nested Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) inside a must clause.

Also note that, in order to make use of **Exact Match**, you should be using [Term Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) on [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) field as shown below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "field",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "field.color.keyword": "yellow"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "field",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "field.fruit.keyword": "banana"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps and if you think that solved what you are looking for, feel free to ***upvote*** and/or ***accept the answer*** by clicking on big gray check button on the left side of this answer.

Comment: In case of full text search, I think you have wrongly specified nested path value "path": "fruit" instead of "path": "field"

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me. It might work if there is no clear match in any of the documents but since there is a clear match in the first document, it still is not checking all the elements of the array. 

Also, the path that I specified is : nestedobject.field.color and nestedobjected.field.fruit for the match and the nested path is: nestedobject.field.

This is because I had not put the nestedobject itself as type nested. Only the field inside is nested. I use elastic version 6.4 and I tried to put nestedobject as nested but didnt work. 

Any suggestions ?

Comment: @achand45 I think I understood what you are looking for and I believe script is the only way to achieve this as via DSL there is no direct way to achieve what you are looking for. Although I doubt if this is possible, let me see what I can do. I'll let you know once I have something.

Comment: @achand45 The only way to achieve what you are looking for is to expand your query and add a `must_not` clause using `Terms Query` and add all the `colours` and `fruits` which you don't want. That way you'd get only those documents which would have what you are looking for.